# Does CentOS have recursive route lookup feature?

Tags: centos, ip, route

I was wondering if recursive route lookup is possible in CentOS? Here is the scenario:

I have 2 NICs on the machine. NIC1 has default gateway. NIC2 needs communicating to outside world to only 2 IP subnets (173.144.4.x & 172.45.5.x). And the NIC2 needs to go through proxy (192.168.1.1). Here is the configuration I am adding this config the second NIC to influence the traffic:

```
Destination        Next-Hop      
173.144.4.0/24    172.20.25.1
172.45.5.0/24     172.20.25.1
172.20.25.1       192.168.1.1
```

> In the above, first 2 are the outside subnets that it needs access to.
> 172.20.25.1 --> Proxy Server IP.
> 192.168.1.1 --> Default gateway address of the subnet that NIC2 has address in.

[EDIT2]
Here is the high level topology:
[image]

Proxy is not transparent proxy. Only NIC1 is configured with default gateway since we cannot have 2 NICs with 2 different gateways in CentOS. NIC2 should be communicating with 2 subnets over the internet, for which the first 2 routes are added. And another route is added for proxy server saying if you want to reach proxy server, using this next-hop (gateway of that subnet).

In theory, when the machine is trying to access the outside subnets, it checks the route table and sees the next-hop as proxy IP, and checks the route table again and sees that to reach proxy IP's next-hop is default gateway.

Does this work in Linux? Does Linux do recursive route lookup as mentioned above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think I really understand this, but do you want to trace the routing or something? If so, I guess you could use `traceroute`.

Comment: I have edited the question now. I want to influence the traffic going through second NIC. Basically, all traffic from NIC2 should go through proxy. In the config, first 2 lines says that traffic to that destination should be forwarded to proxy and to get to proxy use default-gateway address.

Comment: What kind of proxy is it (SOCKS? HTTP? If HTTP, does it support CONNECT)? What kind of traffic to `173.144.4.0` and `172.45.5.0` do you need to route through the proxy, HTTP only, or diverse protocols?

Answer (score 0):

While you can have policy routing with more complicated setups, the default variant (which you seem to be using) is a one-level decision.

The OS looks at the destination address of the packet, it looks for a matching route, and then sends the packet to the next hop for that route.

That's all.

Routes for local subnets are added automatically.

A consequence of that is that **all** nodes on the path need enough routing information to make the correct next-hop decision. That means you need to set up correct routes in **all** nodes, not only the originating node. That's a mistake beginners often make.

So whatever it is you are trying to do (which I don't completely understand), it probably won't work.

Also, if both your subnets are connected to the internet (via a proxy or otherwise), you cannot generically use both of them at the same time to reach the internet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This machine is the end host. So it only needs to send packets out of its interface to the default gateway setting the proxy as the destination. Rest of the packet forwarding is taken care of the routers/switches no?

Comment: Also, basically, with one-level decision (config I posted) CentOS only looks at the route table once and since it cannot find the route to the proxy server, connection fails?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the proxy as a transparent proxy, instead of an explicit proxy, and this needs to be done on this machine, because the other machine doesn't to transparent proxying? Please edit your question and describe the whole situation, and add a network diagram. If you need a transparent proxy, you can configure this both on the originating box and the intermediate box. You need iptables rules in both cases, see e.g. [here](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/)

Comment: And yes, if you don't have a default route (which you'll usually always have...), connections not in the routing table will fail.

Comment: I have added topology and explained a bit more in details what I am trying to accomplish. What I want to accomplish here is If you want to go to Subnets over internet, use proxy server, and to go to proxy server, use default gateway as the next-hop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of proxy that might be applicable here:

- a regular (explicit) proxy
- a transparent proxy (forced proxy)

The problem is, once your system passes a data packet to a gateway, you will have no further say on how the packet is going to be routed onwards: the gateway will make its own routing decisions (usually) based on the destination IP address only, using its own routing table.

There used to be a mechanism called *source routing*, which would have allowed you to specify the route you wish the packet should take; but there were very few legitimate reasons to use it, and it turned out to be useful for many evil acts, so practically all modern routers and gateways will completely ignore any source routing options if they exist in any data packet, for security reasons. If a router/gateway is audited for security, having source routing enabled will most likely cause the router to fail the audit.

---

### With a regular proxy

If you need to use a proxy to connect to something, then as far as TCP/IP routing is concerned, then you will be connecting *to* the proxy. Then, at some higher protocol layer, your client application will *ask the proxy* to make the next connection to the actual destination.

If you need a proxy to access the 173.144.4.0/24 and 172.45.5.0/24 networks, the first step is telling the client application that a proxy is needed to connect to those networks. You cannot do that using just a routing table. There is no uniform way to configure all applications to use a proxy for a particular network: each application can have its own configuration scheme for this.

If the client application is a web server, that can be done using a [*proxy auto-configuration file*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_PAC_file), which is commonly named `wpad.dat` or `proxy.pac`.

For more info, see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol

---

### With a transparent proxy

With a *transparent proxy*, then the situation is different: the client "thinks" it's connecting directly to the destination (using gateways if needed as usual), but some router, firewall or other network device on the way will redirect the connection to the proxy instead. The proxy needs to pretend it is the actual destination... which is becoming more and more difficult with ubiquitous TLS connections, certificate pinning and other added security measures.

If your proxy is a transparent proxy, the routing table at the end host would have to be configured to pass any traffic going to the 173.144.4.0/24 and 172.45.5.0/24 networks to the default gateway, **and the default gateway must be configured to force that traffic to go into the transparent proxy instead**. If the transparent proxy was in the same network segment as the client, you could force the traffic into a transparent proxy using some ARP trickery, but since in your case the proxy is behind a gateway, the gateway must be configured to do the redirection.

---

In both cases, the second step would be to configure the *proxy* to accept requests from the end host only if the destination is in the 173.144.4.0/24 and 172.45.5.0/24 networks, and reject any other requests from the end host.